# saving resultset to String

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm learning MySQL and Java, and i'm trying to create a method that takes the current string in the database and changes it to something else.

My code looks like this:

```
public void changeStatus(int taskID) throws SQLException 
{
    try {
        // 1. Get a connection to database
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPass);

        // 2. Create a statement
        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("select 'status' from tasks where id=?");

        myStmt.setInt(1, taskID);

        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        String statusString = myRs.getString("status");


        if (statusString != null)
        {
            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("update tasks set status=? where id=?");
            if (statusString.equals("New"))
            {
                myStmt.setString(1, "In Process");
                myStmt.setInt(2, taskID);
                myStmt.executeUpdate();
            }
            else if (statusString.equals("In Process"))
            {
                myStmt.setString(1, "Done");
                myStmt.setInt(2, taskID);
                myStmt.executeUpdate();
            }
            else if (statusString.equals("Done"))
            {
                myStmt.setString(1, "New");
                myStmt.setInt(2, taskID);
                myStmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (myRs != null) {
            myRs.close();
        }

        if (myStmt != null) {
            myStmt.close();
        }

        if (myConn != null) {
            myConn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It says that i get java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set. 
I think that the problem is in this line:

```
             String statusString = myRs.getString("status");
```

What do i have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `myRs.next()` before reading from the resultset.

Or better first check if you have an entry in your resultset:

```
if (myRs.hasNext()){
  myRs.next()
  String statusString = myRs.getString("status");
}
```

And there is an other problem in your query:

```
myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("select 'status' from tasks where id=?");
```

you have to remove the single quote arround the column name `status`. It must be:

```
 myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("select status from tasks where id=?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the cursor to the next position before fetching value.

```
myRs.next();
String statusString = myRs.getString("status");
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

> You access the data in a ResultSet object through a cursor. Note that
>   this cursor is not a database cursor. This cursor is a pointer that
>   points to one row of data in the ResultSet object. **Initially, the**
>   **cursor is positioned before the first row. You call various methods**
>   **defined in the ResultSet object to move the cursor.**